# Understanding the config

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-commands

There was this config in my show run config in Cisco 2900 series router.

```
ip forward-protocol nd
!
ip http server
ip http access-class 23
ip http authentication local
ip http secure-server
ip http timeout-policy idle 60 life 86400 requests 10000
```

Is this config the reason i had to restart the biometric devices every single time.
Could you please help me understand this config. 
Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of those commands should have any effect on your networks.

The `ip forward-protocol nd` command simply means that the router will forward ND packets for diskless workstations. This is rather obsolete.

The `ip http` commands are for the HTTP server in the router itself. It is a way to configure the router with HTTP, and it means nothing to anything else connected to the router.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I was thinking this 86400 in the command was the reason for me to restart the router and biometric devices again and again.